# Creating colour flags - Repetition

Tags: java

I am new to this and I don't know what to do and I am totally stuck!

I have created the Armenian Flag and it was easy with the rows.

If I wanted to alter the code so it was horizontal (or like something like the Italian flag with the red, white and green), how would I code it?

This is how I did the Armenian Flag:

```
 import java.awt.Color;

 /**
 * A program to draw an Armenian flag.
 * 
 * @author O
 * @version 5
 */
 public class ArmenianFlag
 {
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
     // the flag has three bands of colour
    // and the aspect ratio is 1:2 (it's twice as wide as it is high)
    int WIDTH = 6;
    int HEIGHT = 3;
    int CELL_SIZE= 60;

    // Mix up the right colours
    Color RED = Color.RED;
    Color BLUE = new Color(0, 0, 170);
    Color ORANGE = new Color(255, 153, 0);

    // Create the window to display in
    FlagFrame frame = new FlagFrame("Armenia", HEIGHT, WIDTH, CELL_SIZE);

    // OK - now we are ready to paint the colours in the right places
    for(int row = 0; row < HEIGHT; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < WIDTH; col++)
        {
            switch(row)
            {
                case 0:
                    frame.selectColor(row, col, RED);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    frame.selectColor(row, col, BLUE);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    frame.selectColor(row, col, ORANGE);
                    break;
            }
        }
      }
    }
   }
```

Comment: Hard to say, you are using some API/lib and don't tell us which.

Comment: You could probably get away with changing `switch(row)` to `switch(col%2)` and then change the colors to green white and red in that order. Also, it might be easier to do it without loops first, then change it to use loops.

Comment: Armenian flag: `RED = new Color(217, 0, 18); BLUE = new Color(0, 51, 160); ORANGE = new Color(242, 168, 0);`.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would leave change your structure a little, so you class looks like this:

```
public class ArmenianFlag
{
    public FlagFrame getFlag()
    {
        // ... Do logic.
        return frame;
    }
}
```

Then you can create another flag, like so:

```
public class ItalianFlag
{
    // Once again, so logic. Bare in mind this time, you want three columns and 1 row.
    int width = 3;
    int height = 3;

   public FlagFrame getFlag() {

        for(int col = 0; col < width; col ++)
        {
            // Cycle through each column.
            for(int row = 0; row < height; row ++)
            {
                // For eaach row in the column, set the appropriate color.

                // Notice the important part is you're changing the color of each column!!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And while you're there, you might as well make a superclass.

```
public abstract class Flag
{
      public FlagFrame getFlag();
}
```

Then the header of your classes now looks like this:

```
public class ItalianFlag extends Flag
```

and

```
public class ArmenianFlag extends Flag
```

You could move out the common details, like height and width to the `Flag` class..

```
public abstract class Flag
{
      private int height;
      private int width;

      public FlagFrame getFlag();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use inheritance.

Create an abstract Flag class something like this.

```
package com.ggl.flag.model;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public abstract class Flag {

    protected Dimension dimension;

    protected String name;

    public Flag(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setDimension(Dimension dimension) {
        this.dimension = dimension;
    }

    public void setDimension(int width, int height) {
        this.dimension = new Dimension(width, height);
    }

    public Dimension getDimension() {
        return dimension;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public abstract void draw(Graphics g);

}
```

Then, you extend this class, adding whatever fields you need to code the draw method.

For example, this would draw an Italian flag.

```
package com.ggl.flag.model;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class ItalianFlag extends Flag {

    private Color   green;
    private Color   white;
    private Color   red;

    public ItalianFlag() {
        super("Italian");
        // Use new Color(r, g, b) for a more precise color match
        this.green = Color.GREEN;
        this.white = Color.WHITE;
        this.red = Color.RED;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        // Flag dimensions are 3 x 2
        int colorWidth = dimension.width / 3;
        g.setColor(green);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, colorWidth, dimension.height);
        g.setColor(white);
        g.fillRect(colorWidth, 0, colorWidth + colorWidth, dimension.height);
        g.setColor(red);
        g.fillRect(colorWidth + colorWidth, 0, colorWidth + colorWidth
                + colorWidth, dimension.height);
    }

}
```

Your DrawingPanel class would extend a JPanel and draw whichever flag you pass as a constructor parameter.

```
package com.ggl.flag.view;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import com.ggl.flag.model.Flag;

public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = -1489106965551164891L;

    private Flag flag;

    public DrawingPanel(Flag flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
        this.setPreferredSize(flag.getDimension());
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        flag.draw(g);
    }

}
```